# construction of a linear functional in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Can someone help me to construct a linear functional in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ that does not attain its norm?

Actually, I want to prove that $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is not reflexive Banach space. Is it sufficient to construct that kind of functional?

Answer (score 12):

Try $\varphi(f) = \int_{0}^{1/2} f(x)\,dx - \int_{1/2}^{1} f(x)\,dx$.

As for the second question, yes. For every $x \in X$ there is by Hahn-Banach a functional $\varphi \in X^{\ast}$ with $\|\varphi\| = 1$ such that $\varphi(x) = \|x\|$. Now apply this to $X^{\ast}$ and use reflexivity.

Comment: Sir , I am trying to see why $||\phi||=1$ . Can you give me some hints . I would like to work it out.

Comment: $\leq$ is trivial, for $\geq$ take $f$ piecewise linear, constant equal to $1$ on $[0,1/2 - \varepsilon]$ and constant equal to $-1$ on $[1/2 +\varepsilon, 1]$.

Comment: i don't get it why $\le$ is trivial, can u give me more details .

Comment: triangle inequality + $\lvert \int f \rvert \leq \int \rvert f\lvert$.

Comment: yes , got it . But are you sure for $\ge$ the function u gave will work ?

Comment: Sir that will be ,$\phi (f)\ge \int_0^{1/2-\epsilon}|f|-\int_{1/2+\epsilon}^1|f|$ right , it doesn't seem to work ?

Comment: And can i show that it doesn't attain its norm without using reflexivity ?

Comment: Try again: $$f_\varepsilon(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \leq x \leq 1/2 - \varepsilon \\ \text{linear} & \text{on }1/2 - \varepsilon \lt x \lt 1/2+\varepsilon \\ -1 & 1/2 + \varepsilon \leq x \leq 1.\end{cases}$$ You should get  $\varphi(f_\varepsilon) = 1 - \varepsilon$ while $\lVert f_\varepsilon \rVert = 1$, now let $\varepsilon \to 0$. Yes, no reflexivity needed: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129751/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80773/).

Answer (score 6):

Knowing some deeper theorems will help to see what to do.

The Riesz representation theorem says that the continuous linear functionals on $C([0,1])$ are precisely the signed Radon measures on $[0,1]$.  It's not hard to see that any bounded measurable function is a continuous linear functional on the space of signed measures, i.e. is an element of $C([0,1])^{**}$.  So the existence of bounded discontinuous functions on $[0,1]$ shows that $C([0,1])$ cannot be reflexive.