# Prove that $K,$ a closed convex subset of $\left(C[0,1],\|\cdot \|_{\infty}\right)$ contains no element of minimum norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E=\left(C[0,1],\|\cdot \|_{\infty}\right)$ and $K$ be a closed convex subset of $E$ which consists the set of all $f\in E$ such that
$$\int^{1/2}_{0}f(s)ds-\int^{1}_{1/2}f(s)ds=1.$$
Prove that $K$ contains no element of minimum norm.

**My trial**

Suppose for contradiction, that it contains an element of minimum norm. This element can either unique or not. Assume that it is unique. Then, there exists $f_0\in K$ such that $$\|f_0\|=\inf\limits_{f\in K}\|f\|.$$
By characterization of $\inf$, there exists $(f_n)_n\subseteq K$ such that $\|f_n\|\to \|f_0\|\in K.$ However, $(f_n)_n\subseteq K$ implies $(f_n)_n\subseteq \left(C[0,1],\|\cdot \|_{\infty}\right)$ and

$$\int^{1/2}_{0}f_n(s)ds-\int^{1}_{1/2}f_n(s)ds=1.$$

From here, I don't see how to arrive at a contradiction. Can anyone further help?

Comment: Exactly the same question was asked few years ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80773/a-vector-without-minimum-norm-in-a-banach-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of $K$  we see that $1 \leq ||f||$ for all $f \in K$. Let $f_n(x)= 1$ for $x \leq \frac 1 2$, $-2nx+1+n$ for $\frac 1 2 \leq x \leq \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 n$ and $-1$ for $ x\geq \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 n$> Let $c_n=\int_0^{1/2}f_n(x)\, dx-\int_{1/2} ^{1}f_n(x)\, dx$ and $g_n(x) =\frac {f_n(x)} {c_n}$. You can easily verify that $c _n \to 1$ and $g_n \in K$ for all $n$. Also $\|f_n\| =1$ for all $n$. Putting these together we see that $\inf \{\|f\|:f \in K\}=1$.

Now suppose there is an element of norm $1$ in $K$. Then $1=\int_0^{1/2}f(x)-\int_{1/2} ^{1}f(x) \leq \int_0^{1/2}1+\int_{1/2} ^{1}1=1$. Thus equality must hold throughout. This implies that $f(x)=1$ for $x <\frac 1 2$ and  $f(x)=-1$ for $x >\frac 1 2$ . But this contradicts the fact that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @nicomezi Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Why is $1 \leq ||f||$ for all $f\in K$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger $1=|\int_0^{1/2} f(x)dx-\int_{1/2}^{1}f(x) dx|\leq \int_0^{1/2} M+\int_{1/2}^{1} M=M$ where $M$ is the supremum of $|f(x)|$.

Comment: I see! How it's obvious also to me. 

Answer (score 2):

Show that $\|f\|>1$ for all $f\in K$, but for every $c>1$, you can find $f\in K$ with $\|f\|=c$. (The idea behind this is that there is an "obvious" minimizer if you drop the demand for continuity)